# Sending POST mono for android

Tags: android, post, mono, xamarin.android

How can I send jpg file and strings via POST in Mono for Android?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpWebRequest to construct a Post request, serialize your jpg and include the serialized text as a post variable along with your other string values.  I do this in my Monodroid app in similar fashion to what is described here: http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/12/16/posting-multipartform-data-using-.net-webrequest.aspx